# Header Logo Image URL Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, url, image, logo

How to Change Header Logo Image URL Magento 2.1. So I click the header logo to go to another website.

Comment: You are asking about favicon ? Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Why you want to change header logo URL? elaborate more.

Comment: So I click the header logo to go to another website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/logo.phtml` in your `theme`.

Your theme path is like : 
`app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml`

[image]

You can add your URL here.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_src" xsi:type="string">images/logo.png</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If needs use "theme" url:

Copy

`app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header/logo.phtml`

to

`app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml`

and change

`src="<?= $block->getLogoSrc() ?>"`

to

`src="<?= $block->getViewFileUrl($block->getLogoSrc()) ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration-> <your theme> -> Header settings -> logo
```

Comment: this will change logo image. not URL of the image. thank you